# Can a long-time expired PR be a shareholder of a private limited company in Singapore?

Tags: visa, singapore

Will a shareholder with an expired Singapore PR be considered a local shareholder?

Answer (score 1):

A non-resident can be a shareholder in a PLC in Singapore: I enquired last year with a couple of accounting companies in Singapore about creating a PLC in Singapore as a non-resident foreigner, and they said it was possible (although it required TWO shareholders minimum, and a PR is required as Director).

If your PR is expired, you're not a PR anymore, and your former status doesn't count, one way or another. Your are a non-resident, period. But since non-residents can be shareholders, you're all good.